# Jquery post and html form validation

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, post

I $.post(); correctly some forms elements with jquery.
Now, some of these elements are "required", of course I can test server side if they are correctly filled and return back a response, but it would be nice if I could trigger the classic HTML required  error, where it also evidences the missing fields. Of course I'll test them serverside after, but  at least I don't have to do the highlighting with javascript.

I don't like creating an hidden post button. Also because I post more than one form at once

```
formX.serialize() + formX+1.serialize() + ...
```

I'd like to know if there is a way. Thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this jQuery plugin to validate your form: https://jqueryvalidation.org

You can do something like this:

```
$("#formX").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
      $(form).ajaxSubmit();
   }
});
```

Comment: Since no other comments, are added.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `serializeArray` method in jQuery as well.: https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var oParams = {
    'invalid_msgs' : {
      'title' : 'Kindly provide the title',
      'body' : 'Kindly provide the body',
      'type' : 'Kindly provide the type'
  },
};

$('#frm-add-content').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var oFormData = $(this).serializeArray();
    // console.log(oFormData);

    for (var iIndex in oFormData) {

        if (oFormData.hasOwnProperty(iIndex) === true) {
            var sInputKeys = oFormData[iIndex].name; // (e.g title)
            var sInputValues = oFormData[iIndex].value; // (e.g Title 1)

            /* If in case there are [input] fields that
             * are not required in this case, You can set
             * condition like this
             * In this case, The input that had the [author] 
             * name attribute will be 'exempted' for validation
             */
            var aNotRequiredInputKeys = ['author'];
            if ($.inArray(sInputKeys, aNotRequiredInputKeys) < 0) {
                if ($.trim(sInputValues) === '') {
                    alert(oParams.invalid_msgs[sInputKeys]);
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
    }

});

});
```

Here's a jsfiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/xdp70kt3/2/

Hope this will guide you well.

On the other note, You can also add `required` html attribute as well if
you only want to check if the values were inputted.